# Keep main content beneath fixed header

Tags: jquery, header, offset, fixed

Quite new to jQuery so sorry if this is basic.

I want my main content wrapper to always be beneath the fixed header. This would be ok if the fixed header was always the same height, but it is responsive and it's height changes.

This is my jQuery thus far (which doesn't work):

```
var banner = $('div.banner');
var wrapper = $('div.wrapper');

wrapper.offset().top = banner.outerHeight() + wrapper.offset().top;
```

I thought by defining `wrapper.offset().top` as the same value as the the banner's height at any given moment, this would work. Sadly no.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it within doc ready block and use `css()` method to set the `top` property:

```
function setHeader(){
    var banner = $('div.banner');
    var wrapper = $('div.wrapper');

    wrapper.css('top', banner.outerHeight() + wrapper.offset().top);
}
$(function(){
    var time;
        time = setTimeout(function(){
           if(time){ clearTimeout(time);}
           $(window).resize(setHeader).trigger('resize');
        }, 700);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This sets it fine on refreshing the browser, but on resizing the window, the main content quickly sinks downwards and disappears...

Comment: Then you need to have delay like `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()`.

Comment: Ok, I've fixed it so the main content appears below the fixed header. Problem #1 solved.

My issue now is to make it so on adjusting the window, when the fixed header height changes, jQuery is constantly checking this, and 'fixes' the wrapper offset position accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. Still not working unfortunately. The timeout is responding, but again, when I resize the window, the main body flies down the screen - albeit not so rapidly this time.

Comment: _Still not working_ is not helping would you mind to setup a demo at https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Sorry. Have made a rough version here: https://jsfiddle.net/u6fLm2oo/ Same principles apply.